# What role does the phrase "the way" perform in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> Walter thought she was wonderful **the way** she was (1). Whatever she
>   did, he marveled. If she espoused extreme points of view, he was
>   impressed by her arguments; when she shocked society by helping
>   unmarried mothers and their children, he admired her courage; and he
>   loved **the way** she looked in daring fashions (2). 
>  (Ken
>   Follett, Fall of Giants)

It seems like the second the way phrase is the complement of ‘loved’ (or the object). But the first is not that easy. It seems to be an adverbial or a predicative for ‘she’. How do I understand the first the way phrase?

Comment: It might help to note that the first instance could credibly be replaced by ***as*** (or somewhat less credibly, by ***how***). Whereas the second instance could definitely be replaced by ***how*** (idiomatically, ***as*** wouldn't work there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *the way* in both instance means *the manner*.

In the first instance, it is an adverbial phrase modifying the adjective *wonderful* (which is a predicate adjective modifying *she*). It could also be expressed

> *wonderful [in] the way she was*.

*The way* and what follows explains why she is wonderful.

The second instance is a direct object

> He (subject) loved (verb) way (direct object)

*The way* and what follows is *what* he loves. There is an implied *that* following *way* beginning an adjectival clause defining *way*.

Answer (score 4):

The word **way** means literally a track or a road. But it can also be used metaphorically to mean a particular style or state of being. Just like you can walk to the same place by different roads or **ways**, you can look and behave in different **ways**. For example, she could look many different **ways**, she could dress well or badly, she could look beautiful or not, have bad breath or swear like a sailor, but he liked her anyway, the way she was.